# Number of Managers

Tags: code-golf

A company is arranged in a heirarchical structure, with a layer of workers at the bottom. Each worker is managed by a manager. Consequently, each manager is managed by another manager until there is a company "boss". Each manager is restricted to managing, at most, `x` workers. For a company of size `y` calculate the number of managers required (including the boss)

Function should take two inputs. 
Eg non-golfed definition: 
`calc_num_managers(num_workers, num_workers_per_manager)`

You can assume that the number of workers per manager will be greater than 1.

Examples:

- A company with 0 workers needs 0 managers
- If the company has 4 workers, and each manager can manage 8 workers, then there is 1 manager.
- If the company has 4 workers, and each manager can manage 4 workers,  then you need 1 manager
- If the company has 12 workers, and each manager can manage 8 workers, then there are 3 managers:
  [image]

Comment: I don't understand "_If the company has 12 workers, and each manager can manage 8 workers, then there are 3 managers (two team leaders and a boss)_" and the next one either : `11*3 = 33`, which is far more than 20, why not 7 managers (`7*3=21`) ?

Comment: "*two team leaders and a boss*" - This needs to be expanded on.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to PPCG. You should consider posting in [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) first. Your examples make no sense. I´d say 7 or 5 managers for the last example, depending on wether the managers are workers too or not.

Comment: At first I thought, you were asking for `ceiling(y/x)` but now I'm confused..

Comment: I have clarified the question.

Comment: @sdfgeoff So it is a pyramid scheme where each new layer can handle `x` employees until the top of the pyramid when there is only 1? What happens when managers can only handle one or no employees? What happens with empty companies? etc...

Comment: Empty companies have no managers (seems obvious to me, but I will add it to examples), and the case of managers handling one employee is mentioned at the bottom of the question - probably not the best place to put it, so I've moved it further up.

Comment: I propose making the examples easier to read/understand and also reformatting the whole challenge a bit. Have a look at some other recent challenges around the site to get an idea.

Comment: Still not clear, why 3 managers are needed.. [here](http://termbin.com/y9hr)

Comment: So the managers need to be managed too? But aren´t they workers then?

Comment: @BruceForte I assume it is because it's a pyramid scheme but I do agree it's unclear as to why.

Comment: Can't the last case be done with just two managers?  One manager manages 8 people so that leaves 4 remaining, the other manager can manage the 4 workers and the other manager, thats a total of 5 which is less than 8.

Comment: And who manages those two managers. Because it's heirachical, there eventually should be just one "boss". As Titus says, yes, the manages need to be managed,

Comment: The second manager *is* the one boss in Wheat Wizard's organogram.

Comment: Do we assume that the `num_workers_per_manager` parameter is always greater than 0 ?

Answer (score 6):

### C, C++, Java, C#, D : <s>73</s> 69 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Zacharý

Due to the similarities between theses languages, this answer works for each.
Maybe it works in processing too, but i can't test

```cpp
int c(int w,int p){int r=0;do{w=(w+p-1)/p;r+=w;}while(w>1);return r;}
```

Here is an optimized version in **D : 62 bytes** thanks to Zacharý

```d
T c(T)(T w,T p){T r;do{w=(w+p-1)/p;r+=w;}while(w>1);return r;}
```

T here is a type for template metaprogramming. This function is callable with `c(4,8);`

Comment: Amazing, one code for 3 langs))

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков 4* languages. Just edited to test for C :)

Comment: And how about includes ? https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/when-do-i-have-to-include-things-like-javas-public-static-void-main/7516#7516

Comment: @ЕвгенийНовиков Well, the question just says to have a function, not a full program

Comment: I think this works in D (wow, actually a decent D answer) and Processing as well.

Comment: @Zacharý Are you sure about that ? If not, is there anyway to "test" that without downloading the compiler ? I currently have a internet connection that struggle to deliver a 144p youtube video.

Comment: https://tio.run/, and just 144 pixels?!

Comment: I've tested D on my machine.
I am unsure of Processing.

Comment: Converting it to D would actually save you two bytes (in D, the `=0` is not needed).

Comment: @Zacharý Tested in D with TIO, but it does not seems they also have processing. And for my internet connection, let's just say i'm far far away from big cities with broadband fiber connections, in a country where unlimited internet connections is pretty rare. I will update my post for optimized D version

Comment: Sorry for the spam! I know D passes `int`s by value, but I'm not sure about C/C++/C#/Java, if they all pass an `int` by value rather than by reference, you could remove `t` and change all occurrences of `t` to `w`.

Comment: @Zacharý C, C++, Java and C# all pass by values in this case

Comment: Also, D's solution can become `T c(T)(T w,T p){T r;do{w=(w+p-1)/p;r+=w;}while(w>1);return r;}`, since D has a golfy template system.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
Ṃ÷⁴Ċ0Ṃ’$?µÐĿḊS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzqbD2x81bjnSZQBkPmqYqWJ/aOvhCUf2P9zRFfz//39Do/8WAA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>46</s> 43 bytes

If scheme isn't solvable, there will be stack exeeded error

-3 bytes `ceil` trick inspired by *Cows quack*

```js
f=(w,m)=>(r=0|(w+m-1)/m,r>1&&(r+=f(r,m)),r)

//test
;[[0,1],[4,8],[4,4],[12,8],[8,3],[10,3]]//0;1;1;3;4;7
.map(e=>console.log("w="+e[0]+" m="+e[1]+" result="+f(e[0],e[1])))
```

### Requirements

`w` count of workers, non-negative integer

`m` count of max workers per manager, positive integer

Comment: I believe `|1` is shorter than `Math.ceil`

Comment: @Cowsquack `(19/10)|1` is `1`, but ceil `2`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 + 1 (-n) = 45bytes

```perl
$t=<>;$m+=$_=1+int$_/$t while($_>1);say$m|$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lxNbGzlolV9tWJd7WUDszr0QlXl@lRKE8IzMnVUMl3s5Q07o4sVIlt0Yl/v9/Qy6Lf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7r5gEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
ΣtU¡(⌈/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9ziktBDCzUe9XTo//8PAA)

Repeatedly (`¡`) takes the ceiling (`⌈`) of the division (`/`) of the number of workers by the number of workers per manager and sums (`Σ`) all the unique results (`U`).